# Fcatorial Sum not working correctly

Tags: c, loops, factorial

I am using Dev c++ and my code is in c .
I want to program a summ-calculator . that sums the number of terms of the following series

1/1! + 2/2! + 3/3! + ....
terms are taken from the input

here is my code but it hangs when i run it

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(void)
{
long i,j,facto=1,inp;
double sum=0;
scanf("%ld",&inp);
for (i=0;i<inp;i++)
{
    for (j=i;j>1;j--)
    {
        facto *= j;
    }
    sum += i / facto;
}
printf("%f",sum);

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What input did you supply when running the program?  The call to `scanf` means it will wait for some input.  (Did you type a number?  Did you press enter?)

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems with the code:

1. You don't need to have the inner loop at all. This takes up much of the time, and is probably why you don't see the output often (probably the reason for *hang* ing). Do like this:

   ```
   facto = 1;
   for (i=1;i<=inp;i++)
   {
       facto *= i; 
       sum += i / facto;
   }
   ```
2. Since both `i` and `facto` are `int`s, `i / facto` is `0` most of the time. So modify it.

   ```
   sum += 1. * i / facto;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`for (i=0;i<inp;i++)` 
to
 `for (i=1;i<=inp;i++)`

And
 `for (j=i;j>1;j--)`
to `for (j=i;j>=1;j--)`

And
 `sum += i / facto;`
to `sum += i*1.0 / facto;`

And
 After `sum += i*1.0 / facto;` put `facto =1;`